# Documentation generator for documenting project directory structure

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, doxygen

I want to document the directory structure of my project. The scenario may like:

1. Write the file description in each file, following docs format like Sphinx, Doxygen, etc. Directories and files not supporting docstring (image, binary, css, js, etc.) need other method to describe (eg. manually describe in document)
2. Use some tool to collect those description and generate into a document. The output may look like:

```
mysite/                     # root directory    
├── mysite/                 # actual Python package for your project
│   ├── __init__.py         # an empty file that tells Python that this directory should be considered a Python package
│   ├── settings.py         # settings/configuration for this Django project
│   ├── urls.py             # the URL declarations for this Django project; a “table of contents” of your Django-powered site
│   └── wsgi.py             # an entry-point for WSGI-compatible web servers to serve your project
├── static/                 # directory store static files
│   ├── style.css           # style for your website
│   ├── script.js           # some JavaScript code for dynamic content
│   └── logo.png            # website logo
└── manage.py               # a command-line utility that lets you interact with this Django project in various ways
```

It may has some features like toggle button to expand or collapse a directory sub-tree.

I can accomplish this by run `tree` command and manually describe each entry. But it is difficult and takes time when my project grows, I need to copy/paste every newly created directory/file to my document while preserving the directory structure.

Is there any tool or extension/plugin (for documentation generator like Sphinx, Doxygen, etc.) to archive my goal? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could probably use doxygen  add a `## \file \n # \brief some brief description` to each file and on the files page you will see this information.

Comment: For software recommendations, go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.